# Did anyone solve this error: Failed to load resource: the server responded with a status of 403() while trying to login with google?

Tags: javascript, authentication, google-cloud-platform, vuejs3, google-signin

I have been trying to introduce an option to log in with google using my webpage and using vue3, google console and the library 'vue3-google-signin' but am unable to make the code work beacuse of that problem and 'm=credential_button_library:48 [GSI_LOGGER]: The given origin is not allowed for the given client ID.' this one, could anyone help me?

When I press the button I created I am actually able to open a new tab with https://accounts.google.com/ but the content is empty, I am supposing that the problem came from the errors I wrote.

This id the code:

```
<template>
  <GoogleSignInButton
    @success="handleLoginSuccess"
    @error="handleLoginError"
  ></GoogleSignInButton>
  <!-- You can add more UI elements here as needed -->
</template>

<script setup>
import { GoogleSignInButton } from 'vue3-google-signin';

const handleLoginSuccess = async (response) => {
  const { credential } = response;
  console.log("Access Token", credential);

  try {
    // Send the credential to your backend for verification and user identification
    // Assume authenticateUser is a method that does this
    const user = await authenticateUser(credential);
    // Store user information in local storage or a global state
    localStorage.setItem('user', JSON.stringify(user));
    // Update UI to reflect user is logged in
    // This could be showing a logout button, user info, etc.
  } catch (error) {
    console.error("Authentication error:", error);
    // Handle authentication errors
    // Update UI to reflect error
  }
};

const handleLoginError = (error) => {
  console.error("Login failed:", error);
  // Update UI to inform user about the login failure
  // This could be showing an error message to the user
};
</script>
```